# Strange co_filename for file from .egg during tracing in Python 2.7

Tags: python, egg, python-internals

When tracing(using sys.settrace) python .egg execution by Python 2.7 interpreter `frame.f_code.co_filename`    instead of `<path-to-egg>/<path-inside-egg>` eqauls to something like `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/<path-inside-egg>`

Is it a bug? And how to reveal real path to egg?

In Python 2.6 and Python 3 everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not a bug. Eggs, when being created, have their bytecode compiled in a `build/bdist.<platform>/egg/` path, and you see that reflected in the `co_filename` variable. The `bdist` stands for binary distribution.

Comment: Perhaps `.f_globals['__file__']`? I usually just use `u` and `d` to go through stack frames.

Comment: Thanks, that works! `frame.f_globals['__file__']` contains path to .pyc file, but it is indeed path to file in correct .egg